# What is difference between Quantum optics and photonics in general?

Tags: optics, quantum-optics, nanoscience, photonics

Might be a vague Question, But I'm hard to understand it.
My Interest is Quantum optics, which studies Atom optics, Optical coherence, and experimentally proven foundations of Quantum Mechanics.

Theoretically, Photon itself was defined by certain energy conditions (It may be called, Coulomb Gauge) and purely has a characteristic that only can be described as a quantum mechanical process.

However, As a research field, Photonics(especially Nanophotonics) treats the Photon itself too. Also considering the research field that studies the non-linear optical characteristics of solids, It may be related to the study topic which is easy to find in the study field of Quantum Optics such as an SPDC or the Squeezed state.

What could be the difference between those two study fields?

Comment: Quantum optics is a branch of physics (both theoretical and experimental). Photonics usually refers to engineering applications of quantum optics and material sciences related to the manipulation of light. A photon is simply a small amount of electromagnetic field energy. Neither quantum optics nor photonics are manipulating photons. They are manipulating the electromagnetic field to achieve the desired photon statistics.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. It seems they had a difference as a fundamental aspect.